# Technical analysis in Python - source of knowledge

Tags: analysis, python

I did my best, but I could not find answer for this one - is there any good and in-depth source of knowledge about using Python for technical analysis ? Obviously, there are plenty of tutorials, blogs etc., but they are scattered around the web. I'm looking for something comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put this down as a comment, but don't have the reputation to do so. There is (or at least used to be) a [two part MOOC course over at Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/compinvesting1) by one of the developers of [QuantSoftware Toolkit](http://wiki.quantsoftware.org/index.php?title=QuantSoftware_ToolKit). This is not an endorsement of the course or the software, just a statement of fact (for the record, I did do a part of the course, but found it too simplistic and dropped out. The library was easy enough to use, though, with extensive tutorials as to its inner workings available online).

Comment: I believe your answer is quite alright. I'm sure that more can be said but IMHO this an helpful answer.

Comment: That course is pretty poor, would be OK only for absolute beginners. It will give you the right idea of how to use Python for such things. Otherwise, if you get Python basics and know math, I don't think any special tutorial is necessary for this...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps you directly but matplotlib (a library for graphs in Python) has some examples of use of technical analysis ie:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_work2.html?highlight=finance
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html?highlight=finance